# Magento 2.1 Admin Url not found on server

Tags: magento-2.1

I just installed fresh magento 2.1 CE.Everything went fine. But I can not login to Admin panel. This is the error.

The requested URL /admin_****** was not found on this server.
Any easy solution?

Answer (score 3):

Add this htaccess file in your root folder

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.0.4/.htaccess

Answer (score 3):

You can take help from given below link.

http://brijeshtech.in/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy/

Answer (score 2):

Edit apache2.conf file and change following

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

OR

just add the .htaccess file in root folder.

Comment: If I put .htaccess file in root folder then this error occurs  You don't have permission to access /admin_***** on this server.

Comment: Did you try first answer?

Comment: Yes. I tried but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you restart apache server after change the file?

Answer (score 2):

Installing rewrite_module fixed it for me on Magento 2.2 with sample data.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run admin panel URL like `localhost/magento/index.php/admin` and the browser display not found page Then check the file `env.php` in `app/etc/env.php` and check for admin frontend name

---

> 'backend' => [
>       'frontend' => 'admin'   ]

---

if it is the same you are accessing in your browser URL, then go to the database and find table `cor_config_data` and find `web/seo/use_rewrite` change value set `0` then reload your admin panel. I hope it will work 
Thank you...